# How to specify the working directory for the loaded QLibrary lib?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qlibrary

The problem is:
I have a Qt application that dynamically loads a library and executes one function from this library (see code example)

```
...
QLibrary library( "d:/Libs/MyLib.dll" );
if ( !library.load( ) )
    qDebug( ) << library.errorString( );
if ( library.load( ) )
    qDebug( ) << "library loaded";

typedef void ( *StartPrototype ) ( );
StartPrototype Start = ( StartPrototype ) library.resolve( "Start" );
if ( !Start )
{
    qDebug() << "Start( ) failed!";
}

Start();
...
```

And the defenition of Start( ) function froam loaded dll looks like:

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) void Start( )
{
    ofstream myfile( "example.txt" );
    if ( myfile.is_open( ) )
    {
        myfile << "This is a line.\n";
        myfile.close( );
    }
}
```

My Qt application is located at **d:/Projects/MyApp.exe** and when I run it, **example.txt** appears in **d:/Projects/example.txt** (as the current working directory for **MyApp.exe**)

But I want to save **example.txt** in the same directory where my dll is located (**d:/Libs/example.txt**). 
Can I do that without specifying the path directly? I mean is there any way to specify the working directory for the loaded lib and all functions in it? How to set dll path as as a current working directory for dll functions (for example creating file). Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use `QDir::setCurrent()` function?

Comment: Thank you, it works. But what if I have several dll's (each has it's own Start( ) function) and call this functions by signals, for example. In this case I should use QDir()::setCurrent before every Start( ) statement? How  does setCurrent works? Can I have a situation when I set cuurentDir, then run function and then another Start() method would rewrite my previous Dir and the first file would be saved in the second dir?

Comment: You could pass the dlls location as a parameter in start and use it to get the absolute filepath instead of just `example.txt`